# monetdb mapi api, mapi_connect() to remote host

Tags: monetdb

For some reason connecting to a setup monetdb server via

mapi_connect("localhost", 50000, "monetdb", "monetdb", "sql", "demo");

works,

however,

mapi_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 50000, "monetdb", "monetdb", "sql", "demo");

Doesn't work.

I've checked that port 50000 is open, and that the service is up and running.

What am I missing?

Comment: Small update: MonetDB running on windows seems to be working fine, after setting the --mapi_open=true, however, I don't see an equivalent option for my version running on Linux (CentOS). netstat does report the ports being listened to on 0.0.0.0:50000 which is correct... so strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the issue was with Port Forwarding in my VirtualBox settings for my Centos VM. For anyone with similar issue, just add a port forwarding rule, in my case it was for port 50000 (which is what my monetdb server runs on). Good luck.